# Use redux-persist instead of local DB for big data? React Native

Tags: react-native, redux-persist, react-native-sqlite-storage

I am using React Native and want to store notes locally and I was searching out what will be the best way to store data locally. So, first I thought of sql but it's little bit complex then I went towards redux and it's easy to use. So, what will be the best solution for it for large number of data??

Comment: Remember redux isn't for storing data, it is a state management tool. Using redux-presist store the data in local storage. Local storage isn't permanent, the user can clear the data whenever they wish. So it depends upon your data

Comment: Ok so we should use local db for large number of data. In my case it's notes saver in which user will save his notes

Comment: if it is just simple and short notes and there is no authentication or complex data, you can use async storage or persist. Just remember, async storage has size limit so if your data is big consider using DB. Else it is fine to use as you asked

Answer (score 0):

Redux (or MobX) and AsyncStorage would be the best choices to store data locally in React-Native for both iOS and Android.

I would personally recommend you go with Redux as it is easy to implement, use and persist (with AsyncStorage) and handles large amounts of data fairly well.

However, I do not recommend you store large amounts of data locally if this can be done server-side and only needed data is fetched locally.

Only store what is necessary locally to and fetch the rest whenever needed. Of course, this all depends on your app and the data in question. But my answer should cover the general usage of something like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example on how to use redux persist along with redux using AsyncStorage:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import React from "react";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
//store all your reducers here
import reducers from './src/Redux/reducers'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/lib/integration/react'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
//React navigation
import Navigation from "./src/Navigation";
import rootSaga from './src/Redux/Sagas';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  //an array that has whichever reducers you want to persist
  whitelist: ['BananaReducer'],
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers)

const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  {},
  compose(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)),
)

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)

export default function App() {
  const persistor = persistStore(store)

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        <Navigation />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```